# product upload by google sheet failure

Tags: product

I've  failure on running job from google sheet it gives me that message while all data are given \

We can't find required columns: sku. Columns number: "1" have empty headers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file is using the UTF-8 encoding (check this article https://www.webtoffee.com/how-to-save-csv-excel-file-as-utf-8-encoded/) and then try again.

Comment: how could i do it in google sheet

Comment: i updated my answer, pls check.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the correct headers are missing. There needs to be a column header called sku and another one called name.

They have to be all lowercase (SKU and NAME won't work), and they can't have any spaces before or after the header name. sku  (space afterwords) wont work.

Also, are you using a plugin to import?